# How to disable onCreate action when will orientation be changed?

Tags: java, android

How can I disable onCreate event when I turn my device from portrait orientation? Because when application starts it will get much of its data from the Internet, and it will be bad to download this data every time the user turns his device.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Activity tag of manifest write

> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

example:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Comment: Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, you must decalare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Rubix: What does orientation and screenSize value means here. The question is just for my curiosity.

Answer (score 3):

Use a flag check in onCreate. Make flag=true at the time of initialization/declaration
add android:configChanges="orientation" in ur manifest file

In ur java file override the **onConfigurationChanged** method and make the flag as false.

After doing so ur onCreate will be called but the code mention in *if* won't be called.
Move ur code inside the *if* condition.

try using this.

```
static boolean flag = true;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    if(flag)
        Log.d("ONCREATE", "flag is true");
}    
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("ONCONFIGCHANGE", "CALLED" );
    flag = false;
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach is usage of `onSaveInstanceState` method for saving any non persistent data into a Bundle. The state should be restore either in `onRestoreInstanceState` or in `onCreate`. In `onCreate` you have to analyse `savedInstanceState` parameter and if it's not null then you should restore previously saved state.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is by far the best working one.
in your manifest file add

```
<activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:name="your activity name"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      </activity
```

And in your activity class add the following code

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        //do your stuff here
        //
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
  //do your stuff here

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest.xml add android:configChanges="orientation" for the activity.

Answer (score -1):

For C# Xamarin I have this solution:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


public static class ObjectExchanger
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> ObjectList = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Add key and object. Do not add the same key twice.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    public static void Add(string key, object obj)
    {
        ObjectList.GetOrAdd(key, obj);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get object via key. Do net Get twice. Key/object will remove after get it once.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    public static object Get(string key)
    {
        object obj = null;

        ObjectList.TryRemove(key, out obj);

        return obj;
    }
}
```

You can use in in OnCreate Method to backup and restore your data for the activity after rotation.